# Visio (Re)naming shapes as 'sheet' when it should be circle, box, etc

Tags: visio

This may seem pretty idiotic, but here goes: I'm making some networks in visio and I'm literally just cutting and pasting boxes and circles (changing the text) over and over again and adding connectors as appropriate.  I have a macro that then sorts the shape texts based on whether it is a circle or box.

Every once in a while the macro will fail, not because there is a problem with the macro but because one of my shapes (boxes, circles, and even connectors) have been renamed by visio as a 'sheet'.  For example, I copy 'Circle.18' and then paste it right back in, and instead of being 'Circle.19' this shape is 'Sheet.19'.  This can happen when I copy & paste, or when I drag a new shape off the stencil.  It appears to be totally random when this happens, but it messes up my subsequent macro operation so I would really like to stop visio from naming different shapes as 'sheet.xx'

Any ideas?

Is it possible to change the name of a shape in the shapesheet or anything?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the naming works in Visio, and I don't rely on the names for macros.

In your case, distinguishing the geometries from one another is how I would identify shapes.  So if it's a 2D shape, and it has a geometry section with 6 rows, it's probably a rectangle.  If the geometry section has 2 rows, it's probably a circle.

However, I wouldn't necessarily let it get to the point where I'm going off of the shape geometry, unless I want whoever is using the macro to use whatever circle or box shapes they want.  Instead, I would just provide a stencil with a box and a circle shape, and I would either put the different shapes on different layers, or just add a user cell with the type clearly defined.  Then the macro would just look for those shapes specifically denoted as the type I'm interested in.

Comment: Jon's approach is good.  I'll point out, however, that the apparently random name change is almost certainly an indication that the shape has lost its association with its master shape.  The most common reason for this is converting the shape to a group when it wasn't one before.  Using data graphics happens to do this implicitly as well.